# Use pytorch model inference offline data , but it takes too much time

Tags: multithreading, deep-learning, pytorch, multiprocessing

I have trained a pytorch model on 8 GPUs ,then I want to use it to inference offline data.But I have 30 millon samples, and one sample take 30 ms.It take too much time which can't be to tolerate.

Is there a method like multi-thread ?

The code now I use like below:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '1,2,3,4'
model = Model(*******************)
model.cuda()
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
model.eval()
f = open("only-one-file","r")
for line in f:
    result = model(***********)
    print(result)
```

**Note**
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '1,2,3,4' seem not fast as 4 times as a sigle GPU.